# How to make DownArrow key move to next line rather than next code suggestion?

Tags: keyboard

I like to move quickly through my code using the arrow keys. This is frequently frustrated by Mathematica's suggestions of variables to use.

Is there some solution for this? Solutions may include

- Making only one suggestion visible by default so that the down arrow key functionality is unchanged (not preferred)
- Removing that use of the downarrow key (if possible, replacing it with another key, for example shift+downarrow)

I do not want to turn off the suggestions entirely.

Edit: By request, here is a toy example where this problem occurs.

```
abSqVal=1;
abSqVal2=2;
stuff=3;
result=2 * stuff + 1;
```

Now if you want to replace "stuff" in the result with abSqVal, then move to another line with the arrow keys: You cannot, because it wants you to choose between abSqVal and abSqVal2. This kind of thing happened often while writing my code because I have variables that start with the same name.

Comment: Can you describe your process in a bit more detail?  Also, which suggestion dialog are you talking about exactly? For me, using the arrow key I can easily move through lines of code without issues.

Comment: Sure, I will edit a specific example into my question, thanks for asking

Comment: thanks for the example, I think I see what you mean now (even though I can still not reproduce the exact behaviour you describe). One option is to simply press Escape/Return to close the suggestion menu, thereby "accepting" the changes you made to the line. After this point, moving between lines doesn't bring up the dialog again. But I assume you are looking for a different solution?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the example, there was a mistake. It should be reproducible now, if one first runs the program and then tries to make the edit.

Comment: You can press Tab to accept a choice and then you can move with the arrow keys as normal. If you don't want to select a choice you can press the right arrow key to get out of selection mode, too.